# PHP How to round numbers up correctly?

Tags: php, math, sum, rounding

I have a loop which loops items by 24 per time. So it loops 24 items per page. In a page where there are 52 items it does not show the number 3 when I divide 24 by 52.

Example

```
$TotalProductsString=52;
$theLimitOfItems=12;
$TotalPageSum=$TotalProductsString/$theLimitOfItems;
echo round($TotalPageSum, 2); // display 2.17
echo round($TotalPageSum, 2); // display 2.2
echo round($TotalPageSum, 0.60); // display 2
echo round($TotalPageSum, 0.50); // display 2
```

It should display 3 as there is a remainder 52/24 = 2.16 with remainder 4 (24+24=48 + 4 = 52)

Comment: Use the ceil() function. It always rounds up.

Comment: robert: more like rounds up if necessary, e.g. there's a non-zero remainder. if the result doesn't need rounding, ceil won't touch it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try Ceil()

```
echo ceil(4.3);    // 5
echo ceil(9.999);  // 10
echo ceil(-3.14);  // -3
```

From [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php)

Comment: Thanks. Interesting how you can go up and down in PHP. I was using W3Schools.com

Comment: I would always refer to php.net it seems to show most of the answers most of the time ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
echo ceil($TotalPageSum); // Rounds the fraction up
```

Read about the [ceil()](https://www.php.net/ceil) function in the PHP manual [here](https://www.php.net/ceil).